# Zend Framework _forward not working

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework

I am trying to use `$this->_forward()` to go to another action in the same controller but it is not working. My code is...

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->view->bodyCopy = "<p>Please select a file to upload.</p>";

        $form = new forms_UploadForm();

        if ($this->_request->isPost()) {
            $formData = $this->_request->getPost();
            if ($form->isValid($formData)) {
                $this->_forward('displayFileContent');
            } else {
                $form->populate($formData);
            }
        } else {
            $this->view->form = $form;
        }

    }

    public function displayFileContentAction()
    {
        die("In displayFileContentAction");
    }
}
```

but I am not getting my die message. I get an error saying `'Page not found'`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been having real trouble with this.

Comment: camelcase in an action just messes everything up.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you forwarding ? just execute the code, replace

```
$this->_forward('displayFileContent');
```

with

```
return $this->displayFileContentAction();
```

Comment: This displays the index actions view, not the view of the displayFileContent view.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be:

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->view->bodyCopy = "<p>Please select a file to upload.</p>";

        $form = new forms_UploadForm();

        if ($this->_request->isPost()) {
            $formData = $this->_request->getPost();
            if ($form->isValid($formData)) {
                return $this->_forward('display-file-content');
            } else {
                $form->populate($formData);
            }
        } else {
            $this->view->form = $form;
        }

    }

    public function displayFileContentAction()
    {
        die("In displayFileContentAction");
    }
}
```

Notes:

- To forward to the Action you requested you must forward to `$this->_forward('display-file-content')`. Use dashes instead of camel cased.
- You should add a `return` to `$this->_forward('display-file-content')` or your current Action will continue to execute before forwarding to the other Action.
- you must create a view for the other Action and call it `display-file-content.phtml` or just disable the view for this Action using `$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
  $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();`
  .

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try

```
     $this->_redirect('/Controller/displayFileContent');

//Your action 

    public function displayFileContentAction(){
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
    die("In displayFileContentAction");


    }
```

Comment: I have tried $this->_redirect('/Index/displayFileContent'); but it just comes back with an error saying the requested url was not found on this server.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the `$this->_forward('displayFileContent')` you go through the routing stack of Zend Framework. The routing then search for the `displayfilecontent` action which doesn't exists (url are case-insensitive).

To reach that URL you will need to forward to `$this->_forward('display-file-content')`, using dashes instead of camel case.

You will then need to create a view file named `display-file-content.phtml` or to disable view rendering for this action